# How to get particular column of a row data in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We know that for getting data from controller's page into view page in ruby on rails we are using below:

```
In controllers page:
def create
   @user_profession=Profession.where(:UserID => current_user.id)
end
```

And `@user_profession` holds table data and getting data from controllers into view

```
<% @user_profession.each do |user_pro| %>
    <% if user_pro.column_name.first.nil? %>
<% end %>
```

but is there any way to get particular column of a row data either in view or controller page in ruby and I am using this line of code `<% if user_pro.column_name.first.nil? %>` but I am getting an error below

```
undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
```

Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks

Comment: what is column_name here? is this actual column exists in DB

Comment: "Isprivate?" this is my column name.

Comment: you are supposed to use it like this `<% if user_pro.column_name.nil? %>`

Comment: Pavan. It checks all values of this column and I want to check first value means first row value of this column is nil?

Comment: The give it in the controller like this `@user_profession=Profession.where(:UserID => current_user.id).first`

Comment: It gets only the first row data and How do I check column_name.nil? of a first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have to use correct Rails terminology in order to understand how it works:

> A "column" is an `attribute` and a "row" is a `record`. This is very
>   important because it's the basis of the Rails framework -- every time you retrieve data from the DB, you're actually building an `object`, which allows you to call any attribute of that object from your view or controller

Rails essentially creates an [instance variable](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/), and appends a series of [instance methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) for each attribute the object has. You can then call these instance methods every time you access the variable:

```
@variable = Model.find(1)
@variable.attribute_1 #-> outputs column data for column name "attribute_1"
```

To answer your question directly, you need to call the column name itself:

```
@user_profession.first.attr.nil?
```